# Bind several ToggleButton IsEnabled property to other ToggleButtons

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a page which contains 16 ToggleButtons, 12 of which are by default disabled and will only enable once any of the remaining 4 ToggleButtons is clicked. Is there any way to wire the IsEnabled property of the 12 disabled buttons to the IsChecked property 4 enabled ones?

I managed to do this before (and am currently attempting to do it again) using several foreach loops but I imagine that there must be a more elegant way to check if IsChecked == true that doesn't loop through the child elements of their parent grid. Unfortunately the original project was lost during a reformat and no backup of the project file exists so the code has to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: You can do this in XAML via something like `IsEnabled={Binding IsChecked, ElementName=SomeOtherToggleButton}`. However, if you want to make this as easy as possible, you should look into developing your app using the MVVM pattern; modeling this type of behavior in a viewmodel is very easy.

Comment: I am aware of that binding syntax but correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't that only work if you bind to a single element? I need to bind to 4 ToggleButtons so that whenever any one of those 4 becomes checked, the remaining 12 become enabled. I am also aware that MVVM would make my life so much easier but time constraint does not permit it right now.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you needed all four to be active. You can still use an in-XAML binding: just use a `MultiBinding`, with the inputs being the `IsChecked` states from the four toggle buttons. This page (http://tech.pro/tutorial/809/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings) has a quick tutorial on how to get it setup (as well as how to write the converter you'll need.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful info but it seems that MultiBinding is unsupported in Windows Store apps. Ho hum. Looks like a longhand solution is in order.

Comment: There is always time for MVVM.

bind the four available button isChecked each to an individual observable bool property on the VM.   Make the other 12 depend on other observable bool property on the VM, in the getter for this fifth property, test to see if the any of the other four are checked, if so return true.  In the setter of each of the first four, call notify property changed on the fifth bool.

Comment: Thanks once again for another helpful tip. Time constraint referring to the fact that I am very inexperienced when it comes to MVVM and having several other engagements in a day leave me with little time to code much less learn the pattern, however I will look into it once spare time becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start from a blank win8 store app template.

Find MainPage in solution explorer, completely replace the MainPage XAML with:

```
<Page
x:Class="StackOverflowMultiButton.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:StackOverflowMultiButton"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton1" IsChecked="{Binding tbt1_isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton2" IsChecked="{Binding tbt2_isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton3" IsChecked="{Binding tbt3_isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton4" IsChecked="{Binding tbt4_isChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton5" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton6" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton7" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton8" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton9" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton10" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton11" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton12" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton13" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton14" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton15" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton16" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonIsEnabled}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then the code behind with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace StackOverflowMultiButton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainPage_ViewModel();
        } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class MainPage_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    bool _tbt1_isChecked = false;
    public bool tbt1_isChecked 
    {
        get {

            return this._tbt1_isChecked;
        }
        set {

            if (this._tbt1_isChecked == value)
                return;

            this._tbt1_isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("tbt1_isChecked");
            OnPropertyChanged("CommonIsEnabled");
        }
    }

    bool _tbt2_isChecked = false;
    public bool tbt2_isChecked
    {
        get
        {

            return this._tbt2_isChecked;
        }
        set
        {

            if (this._tbt2_isChecked == value)
                return;

            this._tbt2_isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("tbt2_isChecked");
            OnPropertyChanged("CommonIsEnabled");
        }
    }

    bool _tbt3_isChecked = false;
    public bool tbt3_isChecked
    {
        get
        {

            return this._tbt3_isChecked;
        }
        set
        {

            if (this._tbt3_isChecked == value)
                return;

            this._tbt3_isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("tbt3_isChecked");
            OnPropertyChanged("CommonIsEnabled");
        }
    }

    bool _tbt4_isChecked = false;
    public bool tbt4_isChecked
    {
        get
        {

            return this._tbt4_isChecked;
        }
        set
        {

            if (this._tbt4_isChecked == value)
                return;

            this._tbt4_isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("tbt4_isChecked");
            OnPropertyChanged("CommonIsEnabled");
        }
    }



    public bool CommonIsEnabled
    {
        get
        {

            return this._tbt1_isChecked ||
                this._tbt2_isChecked ||
                this._tbt3_isChecked ||
                this._tbt4_isChecked;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Run the app and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Perfect. I really ought to start learning how to do this on my own. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Catch the Click-event of the first four buttons. Let them call the save eventhandler.

In the eventhandle you write the code:

```
bool enabled = tb1.IsChecked && tb2.IsChecked && tb3.IsChecked && tb4.IsChecked;
tb5.Enabled = tb6.Enabled = ... = tb16.Enabled = enabled;
```